# ERR_DNS_FAIL when curl request sent through proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, http-proxy, squid

My proxy has been working fine when I use it to curl general sites like google/facebook etc. But when I try to curl an internal host which should be available I get the following message:

```
<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://x.yz.com/">http://x.yz.com/</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Unable to determine IP address from host name <q>x.yz.com</q></b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>The DNS server returned:</p>
<blockquote id="data">
<pre>Name Error: The domain name does not exist.</pre>
</blockquote>

<p>This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_DNS_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20538a0f427a73%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_DNS_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20%5Bnone%5D%0D%0ADNS%20ErrMsg%3A%20Name%20Error%3A%20The%20domain%20name%20does%20not%20exist.%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Tue,%2007%20Nov%202017%2022%3A18%3A35%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%20192.168.99.1%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0AGET%20%2F%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AUser-Agent%3A%20curl%2F7.43.0%0D%0AAccept%3A%20*%2F*%0D%0AProxy-Connection%3A%20Keep-Alive%0D%0AHost%3A%x.yz.com%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Tue, 07 Nov 2017 22:18:35 GMT by 538a0f427a73 (squid/3.5.12)</p>
<!-- ERR_DNS_FAIL -->
</div>
```

The proxy is set up in the same vm that sets up said host. What should I be looking into? Thanks!

Comment: Is the internal host reachable from the machine where the squid service is running ? Did you check the local DNS settings of the OS where the squid service is running ? What about the hosts file ?

Comment: This is a DNS related issue as reported in the message sent by squid: "ERR_DNS_FAIL"